# What do I do about thinset that has oozed up between the tiles?

Tags: shower, grout

There is too much thinset in between my mosaic shower floor tiles (in some spots it looks like grout). What do I do before grouting?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Must I remove all mortar between tiles before grouting?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/3802/2196)

Answer (score 2):

If your thinset is a couple days old or less then slight wet the thinset sticking out and go at it with a flat head screwdriver.  Usually scrapes out pretty easy the first few days.

Comment: An old hacksaw blade also works. The key is to get to it before it fully hardens (which can take a week or so, but it's getting harder all the time, so step away from the computer and get to it, NOW)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the thinset by grinding it out, otherwise you'll end up with uneven coloring in your grout.  Thinset is also stiffer than grout, and the added rigidity could cause your tiles to crack in the future.  You'd be best off biting the bullet and grinding it out now rather than replacing the tile entirely later!

Comment: A grinder that will remove grout is usually also a grinder that will damage tile. If it's fully hardened, that may be your only option, but it takes a lot more care than the "hand-tool approach".